# How to add a number to Bottom Bar like the image

Tags: android, bottombar

[image: screen shot]

I am currently using a smooth bottom bar library.

Comment: Does your smooth bottom bar library support badge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want to add badge count in `BottomNavigationView` menu?

then use `MaterialComponents` library

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha03'
```

use materialcomponent theme `style.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

in your layout file

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"/>
```

add badge count like

```
val bottonnavBar = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottom_nav)
var badge = bottonnavBar.getOrCreateBadge(R.id.action_add) //R.id.action_add is menu id
badge.number = 2 // it will show count on icon
```

hope it helpss...

Comment: if it works mark it as accepted...

Answer (score 1):

you can use material design guide to do it [from here](https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-app-bar/). also, don't forget to add material design library for android [guide here.](https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using BottomNavigationView then this is easy like a piece of cake. BottomNavigationView provides BadgeDrawable API which you can use to display dynamic information such as a number of pending requests.

According to google doc

> By default, BadgeDrawable is aligned to the top and end edges of its anchor view (with some offsets). Call #setBadgeGravity(int) to change it to one of the other supported modes.
>
> Note: This is still under development and may not support the full range of customization Material Android components generally support (e.g. themed attributes).

You can check BadgeDrawable API docs in details here
https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/badge/BadgeDrawable